# XSLT 1.0: xsl:if test xpath not working for tags without a namespace?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, openxml

Consider the following XML:

```
<mergeddocx>

    <w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships">

        <w:hyperlink r:id="rId9">
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Hello World!!</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:hyperlink>

    </w:document>

    <Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
        <Relationship Id="rId9" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/hyperlink" Target="http://x1y1z1.com/" TargetMode="External" />
    </Relationships>

</mergeddocx>
```

When I try to parse it using the following XSL script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" 
xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"
exclude-result-prefixes="w r">

<xsl:template match="w:hyperlink">
    <a>
        <xsl:variable name="rId">
            <xsl:value-of select="@r:id"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:if test="/mergeddocx/Relationships">
            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                <xsl:value-of select="$rId"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:attribute name="target">
            <xsl:text>_blank</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </a>
</xsl:template>
```

Instead of getting the expected output of:

```
<a href="rId9" target="_blank">
</a>
```

What I am getting is:

```
<a target="_blank"/>
```

The xpath in the `xsl:if` is not accepting that there is a `Relationships` tag inside the `mergeddocx` tag. However when I use only `/mergeddocx` in my test xpath, it works fine.

What am I doing wrong here? How do I include non-namespace containing tags in my xpath?

Thanx in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" 
xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"
xmlns:rel="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"
exclude-result-prefixes="w r rel">

<xsl:template match="w:hyperlink">
    <a>
        <xsl:variable name="rId">
            <xsl:value-of select="@r:id"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:if test="/mergeddocx/rel:Relationships">
            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                <xsl:value-of select="$rId"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:attribute name="target">
            <xsl:text>_blank</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </a>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the difference between the xmlns:r and xmlns:rel namespaces.They are not the same.

Comment: thank you it worked. But why `rel`? Is it some sort of default attribute or something?

Comment: @SurenderThakran It's a purely arbitrary prefix I have chosen. You can choose any other prefix you like - except those that are already taken: `w` and `r`.

Comment: @SurenderThakran Please consider accepting this answer if it solved your problem. I also suggest you take some time to read about namespaces and prefixes in XML.

Answer (score 2):

The elements are in a namespace, you have mistaken the namespace prefix for the namespace.

```
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
```

The xmlns attribute sets the default namespace to its value. This element and any other element without a namespace prefix will be in this namespace.

So the actual internal address of the node is:

```
{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships}:Relationships
```

That is why you define your own namespace prefixes in the xslt. Add a registration for that namespace to you Xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" 
xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"
xmlns:rel="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"
exclude-result-prefixes="w r rel">
```

Now you can use it:

```
mergeddocx/rel:Relationships
```

Unlike element nodes, Xpath has no default namespace. To address an element inside a namespace, you always have to use a namespace prefix.

Comment: Nope it didn't worked. But michael.hor257k's worked. Thanx for your consideration thought :)

Comment: It didn't work because the `r` prefix is already bound to another namespace.

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice that. Fixed the answer.